# Redirect TO PayPal Standard working for Events but not contribution pages

Tags: payment-processor, paypal

I have a site where payment for an event via Paypal Std works fine, but a contribution page set to use Paypal Std does not redirect to Paypal but just completes without leaving the site.

There are no errors logged. Could anyone advise what the problem might be?

Comment: What version of CiviCRM?

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's CiviCRM 5.18.4